# Can a conditional logic be added to htaccess multisite to redirect to www and https except for a single domain?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, multisite

I'm trying to find a conditional logic solution for htaccess on my Wordpress Multisite.

I have found considerable speed improvements to the sub-sites by forcing a redirect of each domain to https and www versions by inputing in the htaccess file directly.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the primary domain is a non-www site and that too is redirecting.  I already know a solution where I can input each domain in the htaccess file individually but that slows down the load time of the sites.

What I'm looking to do is to perform a conditional statement to accommodate this, such as:

If website is domain1.com then make no changes else perform the following rewrite/redirect to www and https.

Does such a method exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as of Apache 2.4 there are If, ElseIF and Else directives that you can use to achieve what you are thinking.

To implement it you would use something like this:

```
<If "req('Host') !~ /domain1.com/i">
   {{ Rewrite rules you only want to apply if the domain isn't domain1.com }}
</If>
```

Sources:

- Apache Blog: [New in httpd 2.4: If, ElseIf, and Else](https://blogs.apache.org/httpd/entry/new_in_httpd_2_4)
- Apache 2.4 Documentation: [If Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if)

Comment: Thank you @PeterA!  I tested your solution and it worked up until I went to a subdirectory then I received a 404 error.  Here's what that looked like:

`<If "req('Host') !~ /domain1.com/">
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 </IfModule>
</If>`

Domain1.com works
Domain2.com Works
but...
Domain2.com/page/ comes up as a 404.

I don't get why the 404 would show up for the subdomains but not the main domain.

Comment: Can you confirm that you don't get the 404 when you remove the if directive? Also, are you able to see the url of the page returning the 404? If so, what is the server trying find that it encounters missing?

Comment: When I remove the IF directive, all pages load just fine but I am unable to load the primary domain.  With the IF directive, the pages load the 404 error with the following message included:

The requested URL /bathtubs/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Not sure why the if directive would be impacting this. Do you have other rewrite rules in your .htaccess?